# Looping through a pandas DataFrame accessing previous elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, `FirstColumn` & `SecondColumn`.

How do I create a new column, containing the correlation coeff. row by row for the two columns 5 periods back?

For example, the 5th row would be the R2 value of the two columns 5 periods back, the 6th row would be the corr coeff. value of the columns ranging from row 1-6 etc etc.

Additionally, what method is the most efficient when looping through a DataFrame, having to access previous rows?

```py
FirstColumn SecondColumn
0   2   1.0
1   3   3.0
2   4   4.0
3   5   5.0
4   6   2.0
5   7   6.0
6   2   2.0
7   3   3.0
8   5   9.0
9   3   2.0
10  2   3.0
11  4   2.0
12  2   2.0
13  4   2.0
14  2   4.0
15  5   3.0
16  3   1.0
```

Comment: I have two DataFrames, FirstColumn & SecondColumn. --- Are they Columns or Dataframes ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. One DataFrame with two columns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```py
df["corr"]=df.rolling(5, min_periods=1).corr()["FirstColumn"].loc[(slice(None), "SecondColumn")]
```

Outputs:

```py
    FirstColumn  SecondColumn      corr
0           2.0           1.0       NaN
1           3.0           3.0  1.000000
2           4.0           4.0  0.981981
3           5.0           5.0  0.982708
4           6.0           2.0  0.400000
5           7.0           6.0  0.400000
6           2.0           2.0  0.566707
7           3.0           3.0  0.610572
8           5.0           9.0  0.426961
9           3.0           2.0  0.737804
10          2.0           3.0  0.899659
11          4.0           2.0  0.698774
12          2.0           2.0  0.716769
13          4.0           2.0 -0.559017
14          2.0           4.0 -0.612372
15          5.0           3.0 -0.250000
16          3.0           1.0 -0.067267
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) If it solves your problem please mark it as an answer to close off your question.

Comment: Of course, that's the least I can do. Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shift(n)` method to access the element `n` rows back. One approach would be to create "lag" columns, like so:

```
for i in range(5):
    df['FirstCol_lag'+str(i)] = df.FirstColumn.shift(i)
```

Then you can do your formula operations on a row-by-row basis, e.g.

`df['R2'] = foo([df.FirstCol_lag1, ... df.SecondCol_lag5])`

The most efficient approach would be to not use a loop and do it this way. But if the data is very large this may not be feasible. I think the `iterrows()` function is pretty efficient too, you can test which is faster if you really care. For that you'd have to offset the row index manually and it would take more code.

Still you'll have to be careful about handling `nan`s because the shift will be null for the first `n` columns of your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Pete! I will try both methods. The columns in the question are in fact just random numbers and the dataset is in reality much larger, so I will try which way is faster!               Edit: While trying to use iterrows(), it returns: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift' even when I've tripple checked its a DataFrame. Why is that?

Comment: Well in iterrows() you are looping through the rows/elements of the dataframe so shift() won't work there. shift() is only for the entire dataframe. Those were two separate solution approaches.

Comment: I understand! But how do I access the previous elements with iterrows() ?

Comment: for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    prev_element = df.FirstColumn[idx-lag]

# (where lag is the number of rows to go back)